# Display tomorrow's name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dayofweek, weekday

I am trying to output something similar to the following on our ecommerce website:

```
Order by 5pm today for dispatch on Monday
```

Obviously, the word Monday would be replaced by the name of the next day (ideally the next working day i.e. not Saturday or Sunday).

I have the following simple javascript script that does the most basic version. It simply outputs the current day name:

```
<p id="orderBy">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- 
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                "Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  var now = new Date();
  document.write("Order by 5pm today for dispatch on " + dayNames[now.getDay()]);
  // -->
</script>
</p>
```

Is there a way of manipulating the above code to +1 the day name? So it would output tomorrows name rather than today. Furthermore, is it possible to skip the weekends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way...

```
<p id="orderBy">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- 
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var nextWorkingDay = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1 ];
  var now = new Date();
  document.write("Order by 5pm today for dispatch on " +
                 dayNames[nextWorkingDay[now.getDay()]]);
  // -->
</script>
</p>
```

Comment: I missed that he wanted to skip the weekend. Nice.

Comment: Recommend array literal notation over `new Array`, though.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I'll edit the answer to use literal notation - was just being lazy by cutting and pasting code from the question.

Comment: If I have this on a development site, what's the simplest way of faking the current day to check it works on Saturdays etc.?

Comment: @dannymcc you can provide parameters to the Date() constructor to set "now" to any date you want for test purposes. see this site http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/10585.asp

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner that will also skip weekends:

```
document.write("Order by 5pm today for dispatch on " + 
                                  dayNames[ ((now.getDay() + 1) % 6 ) || 1 ] );
```

- If getDay is Friday (5), then + 1 is 6, % 6 is 0, which is falsey so || 1 makes it 1 (Monday).
- If getDay is Saturday (6), then + 1 is 7, % 6 is 1 (Monday)
- If getDay is Sunday (0), then + 1 is 1, % 6 is 1 (Monday)

No need to maintain a parallel Array.

Comment: It's neat, but I prefer the parallel array because it makes it obvious what the code is doing, and also makes it easy to change the rule - If you find a courier that delivers on Saturdays for example.

Comment: @Noel: Yes, the array would offer more flexibility. Good point. (Though in that specific case, you'd just change the % to 7, and you've got Saturdays.) http://jsfiddle.net/EgFkL/1/

Comment: Also working days are not the same in each country, here in Israel its sunday to thursday, other countries are different.

Comment: @Zachary K: I appreciate that, but the solution was specific to the requirements in the question. Any solution will require adjustments for localization if needed.