# Display message if Javascript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

What is the simplest way to display a note in place of what the script would normally output?

I currently have the following code:

```
<p id="orderBy">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- 
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var nextWorkingDay = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1 ];
  var now = new Date();
  document.write("Order by 5pm today for dispatch on " +
                 dayNames[nextWorkingDay[now.getDay()]]);
  // -->
</script>
</p>
```

(as per [Display tomorrow's name in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843245/display-tomorrows-name-in-javascript))

As an example, the above code outputs the following:

```
Order by 5pm today for dispatch on Monday
```

I would like to have the following if for any reason javascript is disabled:

```
Order by 5pm for next working day dispatch
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming that the user has their clock set correctly and is in the same time zone as you is probably a bad idea. There is no advantage in using JavaScript for this, you should do it server side where you control the environment. Also telling people to order by 5pm today *after* 5pm isn't a good idea either, so you should account for the time of day in the script.

Comment: Also: interesting use of `orderBy`, I usually take it to mean something else ;-)

Comment: Interesting points David, maybe I should find a better way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p id="orderBy">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- 
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var nextWorkingDay = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1 ];
  var now = new Date();
  document.write("Order by 5pm today for dispatch on " +
                 dayNames[nextWorkingDay[now.getDay()]]);
  // -->
</script>
<noscript>Order by 5pm for next working day dispatch</noscript>
</p>
```

Comment: `<!--` and `// -->`? Why are you including protection for Netscape 2 and friends? (Oh, and a `<noscript>` element isn't allowed inside a paragraph IIRC).

Comment: @David Dorward - I haven't touched the original HTML. And you are right the `<noscript>` inside `<p>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use either[`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript):

```
<noscript>
    Order by 5pm for next working day dispatch
</noscript>
```

or put the text into a normal element and hide it with JavaScript.